# How to style diff implementation for PHP with CSS

Tags: php, css, diff

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/#styling

I am following above link to test code.

I have put them together but in the browser but I am not seeing any nice color table just like author mentioned. I don't know how to include `style` code any idea on how to do that?

index.php

```
<?php
// include the Diff class
require_once './class.Diff.php';

// output the result of comparing two files as plain text
echo Diff::toTable(Diff::compareFiles('/tmp/foo1', '/tmp/foo2'));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include CSS on your page, either by embedding it in the `<head>` or by linking to an external stylesheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- external CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <!-- embedded CSS -->
        <style type="text/css">
            .diff td {
                vertical-align: top;
                white-space: pre;
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                font-family: monospace;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    ...
```

The link you provided gives an example of the minimum CSS needed for each `td`:

```
.diff td {
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

It also explains what classes you can style: `diffUnmodified`, `diffDeleted`, `diffInserted`, and `diffBlank`.

This is the CSS from the example page you linked:

```
.diff td {
    padding :0 0.667em;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-family: Consolas,'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1.333;
}

.diff span {
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.333em;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 0 3px;
}

* html .diff span {
    height: 1.333em;
}

.diff span:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.diffDeleted span {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,192,192);
    background: rgb(255,224,224);
}

.diffInserted span {
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,255,192);
    background: rgb(224,255,224);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! i am not programmer get confused.. !